# On OSX\iOS platform,How can we get the dyld LOG info?

Tags: ios, debugging, jailbreak, dyld

When looking at the source code of the dyld(the version of mine is 360.18),
I found a lot of log code.such as

```
    dyld::log("dyld: re-using existing shared cache mapping\n");
    dyld::log("dyld: shared cached region cannot be mapped at address %p with size 0x%08lX\n",mmapAddress, size);
```

The log function is defined as this:

```
void vlog(const char* format, va_list list)
{
    if ( !sLogToFile && useSyslog() ) 
        socket_syslogv(LOG_ERR, format, list);
    else {
        _simple_vdprintf(sLogfile, format, list);
    }
}

void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, format);
    vlog(format, list);
    va_end(list);
}
```

As we can see,the log call the vlog.And The var "sLogToFile" will be set as a file descriptor, if environment var "DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE" was set to a file name. 
    The problem now is that I can't see the log both in GDB and syslog(use idevicesyslog on iOS).neither the file I set by the "DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE".The file will be create,but it is always empty.
How can I solve the problem to get the log info~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I have solved this problem.In fact ,it is very easy~~~you just need set DYLD_PRINT_* environment var,then the DYLD can analysis this variables and then print the log you want.

Comment: In fact,there is another ways to solve this.it is relative to the AF_UNIX socket,you can google it and write a server program to receive the log from dyld~~~~.

Comment: I tried to set `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS`, and `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE` with iOS app bundle file, like `/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxx/MyApp.app/dyld.log`. But get error `dyld: could not open DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE='/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxx/MyApp.app/dyld.log', errno=2`